# How to get the crash info from ApplicationErrorReport class?

Tags: android, crash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Android ICS (api 14) introduced the `ApplicationErrorReport` class with the following info: 
CrashInfo BatteryInfo and ANRInfo. From the class overview it seems that this class refers to all application installed on the device and not for debugging your own personal application.
I cannot seem to reach that information (simulated crashes and anr's)

I tried this code:

```
ApplicationErrorReport appp = new ApplicationErrorReport();
CrashInfo test = appp.crashInfo;
Log.i(test.stackTrace);
```

but i get that test is `null`

How to get the crash information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [ApplicationErrorReport API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationErrorReport.html) it says:

> ApplicationErrorReport()
>       Create an uninitialized instance of ApplicationErrorReport.

This means that the "type" of error is undefined, so it's not a crash report and therefore the crashinfo is null.

**EDIT:**
I took a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/ApplicationErrorReport.java). You can instantiate the CrashInfo part via the method `readFromParcel(in)` where the first `int` in the parcel is the int corresponding to `ApplicationErrorReport.TYPE_CRASH`. Alternatively you can create a CrashInfo object yourself and assign it to the ApplicationErrorReport, but this again requires a parcel if you want to CrashInfo data to be filled.

I tried looking for code where it is used, but the only thing I could find is the [`ApplicationManagerNative`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/ActivityManagerNative.java) (also using  parcels).

```
case HANDLE_APPLICATION_CRASH_TRANSACTION: {
        data.enforceInterface(IActivityManager.descriptor);
        IBinder app = data.readStrongBinder();
        ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo ci = new ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo(data);
        handleApplicationCrash(app, ci);
        reply.writeNoException();
        return true;
})
```